# how to handle csrf token and session expiry in spring security in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, spring-security, csrf

Csrf token getting expired when login page is kept in ideal situation till session expiry. When i try to login it throws 405 method not allowed and shows a blank page. How to automatic refresh token each time when session is expired. Additionally why it throws 405-Method not allowed instead of Invalid csrf token?

Comment: You should get 403 instead of 405. Could you add your stack trace to the question?

Comment: i also face this type of problem ......i get error message form browser "Invalid CSRF Token '5d2732f1-0fa3-4a17-aedc-a08146a1511b' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'."
if you found any solving way please help me..........

Comment: Do you mean **idle** situation?

Comment: damn, i hate when someone had the same issue as i do and didn´t get a solution :c